# How do I generate a notification icon from text?

Tags: android

I am currently developing an app which involves displaying a number from 1 to 60 in the notification bar. How do I implement this? At first I was thinking of
including all 60 number images within the app, but that seemed unintuitive as I would have to provide separate icons for different screen sizes. How can I generate these icons at runtime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you would need to use Drawable for notification large and small icons, you would obligatory change string value to drawable.

I think for this usecase, you can use this library: https://github.com/amulyakhare/TextDrawable

I haven't use that yet, but for Lollipop and higher version of Android notification bar, you may need to set transparent or no-color background for your chars.

Hope it help